# Action on Click second button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I have 9 buttons, and I need to make 9 pages. Every button needs his own page to navigate to when clicked. 1 of them needs to navigate to a website instead of his own activity. So that one is done, and that works already.

Now I need to make an activity for a button so that it navigates to that on click. Once i've done that, I know how to do it and I can repeat that for the other buttons. I have the code listed below for whay my main activity looks like. That is the code for the button that navigates to the website. If any one you can refer me where to place the new code, and how to place it, would be very much appreciated. I'm pretty new to this so it might be an easy question for the lot of you.

I know that you have to change some code in the Manifest as well, but I think i can sort that one out, just the Mainactivity is the problem..

```
package com.example.rodekruis;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static Button button_sbm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }

        public void OnClickButtonListener() {
            button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws");

                             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                             startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
            );


        }

}
```

Comment: You can use webview for That and load url on that webview :)

Comment: What do you mean with that? I've done the webview thing, now i need another button to activate to another activity on click, not to a website.

Comment: I am not getting your question. Please elaborate or put images.

Comment: it mean you have to open other activity by clicking another button ? @koen Hilarius

Comment: I have 9 buttons. The code that i have in my Main activity, which is shown above, is for 1 of the 9 buttons. This button leads you to a webpage. The other 8 buttons, I want to open another activity with those.

Comment: Now the code for that isn't super hard, but because i already have some code, I don't know where to begin, and where to place the new code.

Comment: You want to open a new activity when you press a button?

Comment: Exactly that. For 8 buttons, every button his own activity. I think i just need 1, so i can sort of copy paste that code, just change some name things for them. Don't know where to put the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take some time out and read [Basics First app](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/firstapp/index.html), specially [Starting Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

to answer your question, you'll need to declare 8 new activities (if each of button have a specific task) or 1 new activity (if all button leads to similar content different format or something)

so lets assume its the second case, so you create a new activity i.e. ActivityB (in android you have to register all the activities you are using in Manifest `<activity android:name=".ActivityB"/>`). to start that activity following is the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

so in terms of your code it should be something like below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button6).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button7).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button9).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws");
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button9:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it's very basic, and I've already done it with 1 button. It's just because I already have some code now for 1 button referring to a webpage, which is kind of simular i think, what makes it hard for me to know where to put that new code. If you could just tell me where I can start typing the new code, how many of these "}" i have to skip to start typing new code

Comment: You sir, are the real mvp.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic function to be trigger when the user click the button and check the id of the button clicked.

Example:

```
public void navigate(View v) {
    int id = view.getId();

    Intent intent; 
    if (id == R.id.button1) {
        Uri.parse("https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws1");
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    }
    else if(id == R.id.button2) {
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityButton2.class);
    }
    else if(id == R.id.button3) {

        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityButton3.class);
    }
    //Repeat for every button


    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And set onclick attribute in the button calling this function.

Example:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:onClick="navigate" />
```

Declare your new activities in AndroidManifest.xml

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityButton2"
    android:label="ActivityButton2" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityButton3"
    android:label="ActivityButton3" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Might not have been clear enough. I want the other 8 buttons to open a new activity, not go to a website. I've done that with 1 button, the others have to go to their own activity. 

Its just that i already have some code, so I don't know where to put that new code and how to end and open it and all.

Comment: Edited to launch activities

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to create new WebViewActivity and in this xml class put these code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

and in your new activity class put this code.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws");

    }
```

now open this WebViewActivity On button click.

```
public void OnClickButtonListener() {
            button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                          Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
            );


        }
```